# I use python/requests to get the HTML label information, want to store the result into pandas data.frame

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

I use python/requests to get the HTML label information, want to store the result into data.frame `value_table`, below can't work from `value_table.append(name.get_text().strip(),ignore_index=True)`. Anyone can help ? Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from lxml import etree
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
value_table=pd.DataFrame(columns=['value'])
url = 'https://www.ebay.com/itm/394079766930'
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'lxml')

sku = soup.find('div','u-flL iti-act-num itm-num-txt').get_text(strip=True)
price = soup.find('span',{'itemprop':'price'}).get_text(strip=True)

div = soup.find('div', {'id': 'viTabs_0_is'})
divs = div.findAll('span', {'class': 'ux-textspans'})
for name in divs:
    print(name.get_text().strip()+' ')
    value_table.append(name.get_text().strip(),ignore_index=True)

value_table['sku',:]=sku
value_table['price':]=price
```

Comment: What is your issue? What is your question? Be more specific.

Comment: You have a couple of issues here but I think the best way to start off is what do you want the end result to look like? Because you have 35 different fields that you want to put in pandas but you're trying to do that as a single column of 35 rows. But then you're looking to add a second column of `sku` and third `price` in their own columns with just one number each.

Comment: Right, currently i only want to strore them into one variable as string . how can i do it ? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mostly on track. The only real modifications needed for things related to pandas.

Pandas reads a list as a column. But you can use a linear algebra trick to transpose the list which is written as a row but brought in as a column to a row as intended. Because of that, `value_table=pd.DataFrame(columns=['value'])` isn't needed. From there it's just a few lines.

So, keep everything above the for-loop with the exception of `value_table=pd.DataFrame(columns=['value'])` and replace the for-loop down with this:

```
value_table=[]
for name in divs:
    value_table.append(name.get_text().strip())

values_table = pd.DataFrame(value_table).T
values_table['sku']=skus
values_table['price']=price
```

That will give you (well, as much can be captured in a screenshot)[image]

For a future iteration, you might want to consider if dict suits your needs better.

EDIT: I noticed in the comments you said: "currently i only want to strore them into one variable as string"

That's a simple as `values_table['stringed']=str(value_table)` but it isn't particularly readable, nor easily searchable.

[image]